# Pagoda Box database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, cloud9, pagoda-box

I have just deployed my website with Pagoda Box after developing it on cloud 9 in which it worked fine, but after pushing to pagoda box I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /data/php/connect.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /data/signup.php(5): require() #1 {main} thrown in /data/php/connect.php on line 11

```
$servername = "192.168.0.2";
$username = "username";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "dbname";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I want to connect my existing phpmyadmin database. Unable to find right way.

Comment: The mysqli PHP extension is not installed on your server

Comment: could you elaborate?